# What does it mean for a spline to have a "repeated knot" and how does it affect the derivatives?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, splines

I was reading some materials about spline funtions and there was something about knot duplication or knot repeating:

> If we duplicate an interior knot, it transpires that the resulting basis still spans the space of piecewise polynomials but with one less continuous derivative at the knot. If we repeat that knot three times, then we have two fewer continuous derivatives there. For example, if the spline is cubic, repeating $e_j$ three times means that the first derivative is discontinuous at $e_j$; repeating it four times means that the spline itself is discontinuous at $e_j$. Thus for an *M*th-order spline, repeating an interior knot M times means that there is a discontinuity at the knot.

This is from Linear Regression Analysis by Seber and Lee, page 175.
I do not know what knot duplication or knot repeating means and how it affects the continuous derivatives. Could someone please shed some light on what it means or suggest me a reference in order to understand it?

Comment: See the excellent but difficult book of Carl de Boor [A Practical
Guide to Splines](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953663),
chapter IX. Mutliple knots are well understood for an order 2 (broken
line spline) where a double knot can be used to allow a step.  When
two successive distinct knots are very close, by drawing famous
``hat'' basis functions involving these knots we get a nearly vertical
segment.  Passing to the limit we get discontinuous functions with a
specified location for step.

Comment: Knot duplication is where you place a second knot at the *same* x-value.

Comment: Thank you for your help!@Yves I tried to read the book you recommended but it is really difficult. I post a link which is a lecture about B spline https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkncKzflw8I

Comment: @Deepleeqe B-splines are a different thing than the Bezier spline,
although a confusion of these two notions is quite common. You can
experiment with the B-spline basis with given knots sequence using the
`splineBasis` function of the **splines** R-package (recommended
package usually coming with R), starting from the example in the help
of this function. Taking `ord = 2` or 3 and changing the knots sequence 
can be instructive.

Comment: Sorry the name of the function is `splineDesign`.